# how to concatenate string in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

I need to convert a mailto element to have subject and body element in a javascript.

```
var matterDetail = "?Subject=Potential New Matter";
try{strContact = strContact + "<TD><A href=mailto:" +  EMailNode.item(0).firstChild.nodeValue +matterDetail +">" +  EMailNode.item(0).firstChild.nodeValue + "</A></TD>";}
```

This outputs the html to `<a href="mailto:some@email.com" ?Subject="Potential" Matter="" New="">`

Any ideas what is wrong with string concatenation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classic asp is not written in c#, so i dont know what you are using, but as it seems you are using c#, i would use string.format:

```
strContact += string.Format(
    "<td><a href=\"mailto:{0}{1}\">{2}</a></td>", 
    EMailNode.item(0).firstChild.nodeValue,
    matterDetail, 
    EMailNode.item(0).firstChild.nodeValue
    );
```

EDIT ok, i mistook js for c#!

Your problem is missing quotes in the html attributes, try this:

```
strContact += "<td><a href=\"mailto:" +  EMailNode.item(0).firstChild.nodeValue +matterDetail +"\">" +  EMailNode.item(0).firstChild.nodeValue + "</a></td>";
```

Note the extra (escaped) quotes around the href attribute

Comment: Apology this code is in javascript part of the classic ASP page

Comment: @Learner Ok, i understand now. Please see my edit for the solution

Answer (score 1):

For concatination **&** is used in classic asp:

```
var a = "ehsan " & "sajjad";
```

See [**HERE**](http://www.tizag.com/aspTutorial/aspString.php)

Comment: Apology this code is in javascript part of the classic ASP page